# how to do element-wise operator(substract) in numpy fancy index(more than one same index in index list)?

Tags: python, numpy

My project has just catch a bug, I want to do following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([5,6,7,8])
a[[0,1,1]] -= b[[0,1,2]]
```

I hope the result second `a[1] = a[1]-b[1]-b[2] = -11`,   because there is two index=1 in a[xxx] ,thus I want to a[1] subtract twice. But this numpy code only produce:

```
array([-4, -4, -5])
```

For the reason I want to numpy boost my algorithm speed, thus I only want to write vectorize numpy code (avoid python for-loop)

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: `a[1] -= b[[1,2]].sum()`

Comment: suppose c = a[[1,2,2,3]] - b[[1,2,3,4]] , I want to c[1] = a[2]-b[2], c[2]=a[2]-b[2]-b[3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You need to use [`np.subtract.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) for those accumulated subtraction at given indices with given values -

```
np.subtract.at(a,[0,1,1], b[[0,1,2]])
```

Sample run -

```
In [8]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4])

In [9]: b = np.array([5,6,7,8])

In [10]: np.subtract.at(a,[0,1,1], b[[0,1,2]])

In [11]: a
Out[11]: array([ -4, -11,   3,   4])
```

**Approach #2**

Alternatively, using [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
ind = np.array([0,1,1])
val = b[[0,1,2]]
unq_ind = np.unique(ind)
a[unq_ind] -= np.bincount(ind, val).astype(a.dtype)
```

If `ind` is already sorted, get `unq_ind`, like so -

```
unq_ind = ind[np.concatenate(([True],ind[1:] != ind[:-1]))]
```

**Approach #2S** (Simpler)

If you don't want to mess around with the `unique` work, use `minlength` arg with `bincount` -

```
a -= np.bincount([0,1,1], b[[0,1,2]], minlength=a.size).astype(a.dtype)
```

---

**For accumulated additions**

To use the proposed approaches for adding instead of subtracting, simply replace `np.subtract.at` with `np.add.at` and for the `bincount` methods, replace `-=` with `+=`.

Comment: Thank you so much, You are numpy expert, this bug is really hard to find, I took almost the whole afternoon to find out it.

Comment: @machen Not exactly a bug. With `a[[0,1,1]] -= b[[0,1,2]]`, it just doesn't accumulate and subtract as is intended for your application. But I don't blame you, maybe it could have raised a warning though to be fair.

Comment: Yes, maybe it is the designer's desired behaviour but not my algorithm expected.

Comment: which solution is run speed fastest? does np.subtract.at slow?

Comment: @machen I would use `bincount` for a lot of repeated indices.

Comment: @machen The counter case is where we have initialized `a` as a boolean array. So, an actual `accumulation` would have needed an int array.

Comment: I put your bincount code into a big for-loop, each subtract bincount line may take 0.05 sec, but overall for-loop is iterater over 17184 times, that will take 14.32 minute, and in my machine learning algorithm, this for-loop will be execute 20 times. That means, it will consume 5 hours. Does your provide 2nd solution is the fastest in the world?  Does np.einsum can  further boost speed?

Comment: In my test, solution 1 is slower than solution 3, Does solution 2 time spend == solution 3?

Comment: @machen `einsum` won't work here. I would say test those at your ends and see which one's fastest among these.